# Is there an R function for changing select values in a column from character to integer?

Tags: r, integer, character

I have a df in R in which one column represents ID numbers (e.g., 1, 304, 2039, etc.). This is a very large dataset, and one specific row contains an ID number that is written out in characters (e.g., two thousand thirty two). When I convert all values in the column from character to integer, the text value is now represented as N/A. Is there a way to recode this one text value to its respective integer (2032)?

I did a quick fix in Excel, but wondering what the R code is to handle this for future uses.

Answer (score 0):

The '*wordstonumbers*' package converts a number spelled out into "number".

I tried to convert a vector with numbers and characters but I was not successful. So I created the function to be able to do this job.

OBS.: Apparently converts the word into numbers only in English...

```
#library(devtools)
#devtools::install_github("fsingletonthorn/words_to_numbers")
library(wordstonumbers)

# example
n <- c(1, 304, 2039, "two thousand thirty two")

number <- function(vector){
  b <- NULL
  for(i in 1:length(vector)){
    if(is.na(as.numeric(vector[i]))==T){
      b[i] <- words_to_numbers(vector[i])
    }else{
      b[i] <- as.numeric(vector[i])
    }
  }
  b <- as.numeric(b)
  return(b)
}

number(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 304, 2039, "two thousand thirty two"))`

If you want to replace a *single* value manually, in **base R** you can use

```r
dat$ID[dat$ID == "two thousand thirty two"] <- 2032
```

And with **dplyr**:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat_new <- dat |> mutate(ID = replace(ID, ID == "two thousand thirty two", 2032))
```

This is not ideal because you're hard-coding the string and its integer equivalent, but it's better than fixing it in Excel because it allows this data cleaning step to be documented and reproducible.